# How to download .docx documents with Vue/Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I use Vue with a Laravel API. I created a fileManger. PDF files are working well for download. But .docx files are corrupted after download.

Controller

```
    public function downloadFile(Request $request, File $file)
    {
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: '.$file->mime_type,
        );
        return Storage::disk('local')->download($file->path, $file->name, $headers);
    }
```

Vue/Vuex

```
export const downloadFile= ({ commit }, {endpoint, file}) => {
    return axios.get(endpoint).then((response) => {
        console.log(file.mime_type )
        let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: file.mime_type })
        let link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        link.download = file.name
        link.click()
    })
}
```

When I download the file in PHP Storm from the server, the file is ok. Therefore, the upload process works well.

But I can't open the downloaded file.

I found something about ob_clean, but didn't understand the solution.

Comment: Have you tried returning `return Response::download($file, 'file_name.ext', $headers);` ? Also maybe add a content-length to headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i tried this and it didnt work for me too
dont use ajax or axios
send your request with get-request and in your function return download response:

```
return response()->download(public_path('uploads/TestWordFile.docx'));
```

you dont need to send ajax request.
use GET and when you return some response, page wont be refreshed!
this should work for you

Answer (score 1):

Try using ....

```
public function downloadFile(Request $request, File $file)
{
    return Storage::disk('local')->download($file);
}
```